Salesforce Org Browser in VS Code: ctrl+f stopped working
I used to be able to click on a metadata category (e.g., Apex Classes) in the org browser within VS Code. 
I could then use ctrl+f to bring up a search box where I could type in the first few characters of the name of a class I was trying to find. I could then filter the list to see only the classes that matched my criteria. About two weeks ago that fuctionality stopped working.  Does anyone know how to restore it.  It was a super time saver, as I didn't have to scroll through hundreds of files to find the class that I wanted to open in VS Code.

I discovered the solution. VS Code release 1.89 changed the keyboard shortcut from Ctrl + f to Ctrl + Alt + f to bring up the find dialog in a treed pane, such as the Org Browser. One can also use F3 to open the find dialog box.   Here is the link to Microsoft's documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_89#_find-in-trees-keybinding

You'll want to file a bug on the GitHub repo for this issue. That said, there's other ways to easily get to the file you want. In the force-app/main/default/classes folder in the File Explorer, just start typing the name of the class you want to open. Alternately, Ctrl/Cmd-p will open the command palette. From there, just type in the name of the file you want, it'll suggest as you type. As a bonus, this drop-down will also remember recent files you used.

thanks sfdcfox.  Ctrl/Cmd+p only brings up files already in your vs code project, not new files from the connected org.  Is that not the case when you use CTRL/CMD+p?
